# Converting a list of dates in string to Month, Day, Year in Python

Tags: python, string, list, datetime, strftime

I have a list of dates in a string that looks like this:

```
Date_List
Out[83]: 
['2015-08-24 00:00:00',
 '2015-08-30 00:00:00',
 '2015-08-22 00:00:00',
 '2015-08-21 00:00:00',
 '2015-08-25 00:00:00',
 '2015-08-29 00:00:00']
```

I want it to be formatted like this:

```
Date_List
Out[83]: 
['08-24-2015',
 '08-30-2015',
 '08-22-2015',
 '08-21-2015',
 '08-25-2015',
 '08-29-2015']
```

I tried `Date_List = ['{}-{}-{}'.format(m,d,y) for y, m, d in map(lambda x: str(x).split('-'), Date_List)]`

This returns

```
Date_List
Out[85]: 
['08-24 00:00:00-2015',
 '08-30 00:00:00-2015',
 '08-22 00:00:00-2015',
 '08-21 00:00:00-2015',
 '08-25 00:00:00-2015',
 '08-29 00:00:00-2015']
```

Anybody know how to convert and ignore the 00:00:00

I also tried

```
Date_List = (datetime.datetime.strptime(i, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") for i in Date_List)
Date_List = (datetime.datetime.strftime(i, "%m-%d-%Y") for i in Date_List)
```

but this outputs a generator object?

```
Date_List
Out[91]: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x2047A5A8>
```

Which means if I run the code I get this error: `TypeError: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x1FBCFC38> is not JSON serializable`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're very close; you just need to use a list comprehension on the last line instead of a generator expression.

```
Date_List = (datetime.datetime.strptime(i, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") for i in Date_List)
Date_List = [datetime.datetime.strftime(i, "%m-%d-%Y") for i in Date_List]
```

I would clean it up like so:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pprint import pprint

timestamps = [
    '2015-08-24 00:00:00',
    '2015-08-30 00:00:00',
    '2015-08-22 00:00:00',
    '2015-08-21 00:00:00',
    '2015-08-25 00:00:00',
    '2015-08-29 00:00:00',
    ]

dates = (datetime.strptime(ts, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for ts in timestamps)
date_strings = [datetime.strftime(d, '%m-%d-%Y') for d in dates]

pprint(date_strings)
```

Output:

```
['08-24-2015',
 '08-30-2015',
 '08-22-2015',
 '08-21-2015',
 '08-25-2015',
 '08-29-2015']
```

---

Here's a slightly more generalized way to do it:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pprint import pprint


def convert_timestamp(ts, from_pattern, to_pattern):
    dt = datetime.strptime(ts, from_pattern)
    return datetime.strftime(dt, to_pattern)


timestamps = [
    '2015-08-24 00:00:00',
    '2015-08-30 00:00:00',
    '2015-08-22 00:00:00',
    '2015-08-21 00:00:00',
    '2015-08-25 00:00:00',
    '2015-08-29 00:00:00',
    ]

date_strings = [convert_timestamp(ts, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', '%m-%d-%Y')
                for ts in timestamps]

pprint(date_strings)
```

Output:

```
['08-24-2015',
 '08-30-2015',
 '08-22-2015',
 '08-21-2015',
 '08-25-2015',
 '08-29-2015']
```

Comment: Ah! Wow I did not know about the difference between generator expressions and list comprehensions, good to know!

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Order fixed.

EDIT2: Zero padding fixed after Paulo's suggestion

Try:

```
from dateutil import parser
map(
    lambda d: "{0:02}-{1:02}-{2}".format(d.month, d.day, d.year),
    map(
        lambda d: parser.parse(d),
        dates
    )
)
```

or

```
["{0:02}-{1:02}-{2}".format(d.month, d.day, d.year) for d in map(lambda d: parser.parse(d), dates)]
```

Comment: You're not putting the date components in the requested order. EDIT: And you're not padding the 1-digit components.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @PauloAlmeida, fixed the order.

Comment: You can use something like this to pad: `{0:02}-{1:02}-{2}`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
['{}-{}-{}'.format(m,d,y) for y, m, d in map(lambda x: x.split()[0].split('-'), Date_List)]
```

You don't need `str(x)` because it's already a string. You then `split()` the string, which by default splits on whitespace, and take the first part (`[0]`). You then `split('-')` on the hyphens.